# Pancake Glutton task c++

Tags: c++

I've seen others posted questions on this particular problem, but can someone take a look at my solution please? I used 2 arrays to solve it. I don't understand why the person who has eaten the most pancakes is not reflected? It counts the maximum, but doesn't show the person's number.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array_numbers[5];
    int people[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int i, max = -1, person = -3;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "Enter how many pankakes person "
             << people[i] << " has eaten for dinner\n";

        cin >> array_numbers[i];

        if (array_numbers[i] > max) {
            max = array_numbers[i];
            person = people[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "Maximum number of pankakes is "
         << max << " eaten by person "
         << people[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like *pancakes* for breakfast... they eat *pankakes* for dinner... must be the time difference `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
cout<<"Maximum number of pankakes is "<<max<<" eaten by person "<<people[i]<<endl;
```

Is the problem.  By the time it is reached, 'i' will always equal 5.  What you actually want is:

```
cout<<"Maximum number of pankakes is "<<max<<" eaten by person "<< person<<endl;
```

Comment: Just `...person<<endl;`

Comment: I was assuming that the indirection was there for a good reason.  `person` would actually be one out.  If you want to use it directly you'd want `...person+1<<endl;`.